# ViewPager not Loading Fragments when using TabLayout

Tags: xamarin.android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I got a simple layout with `TabLayout` and `PageViewer` but can't get them to work together

```
   <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs_emoji"    
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:tabMode="scrollable"
        app:tabGravity="fill"    
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/gray"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="1dp"
        android:paddingBottom="2dp"/>
    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager_emoji"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/red"/>
```

In my Activity `OnCreate` initializing the following

```
//Fragment array
            var fragments = new AndroidX.Fragment.App.Fragment[]
            {
                Library.Fun.Emoji.Fragments.Recent.NewInstance(),
                Library.Fun.Emoji.Fragments.People.NewInstance(),               
            };
            //Tab title array
            var titles = Android.Runtime.CharSequence.ArrayFromStringArray(new[] {
                "Recent" ,
                "People"
            });

            var viewPager = FindViewById<ViewPager>(Resource.Id.viewpager_emoji);
            //viewpager holding fragment array and tab title text
            viewPager.Adapter = new EmojiTabsPagerAdapter(SupportFragmentManager, fragments, titles);            
            // Give the TabLayout the ViewPager
            TAB_Layout.SetupWithViewPager(viewPager);
            Toast.MakeText(this, "SET", ToastLength.Short);
            TAB_Layout.GetTabAt(0).SetIcon(Resource.Drawable.ic_camera);
            TAB_Layout.GetTabAt(1).SetIcon(Resource.Drawable.ic_camera);
```

Where the `Adapter` is simple as it could be as following

```
public class EmojiTabsPagerAdapter : FragmentPagerAdapter
    {
        private readonly AndroidX.Fragment.App.Fragment[] fragments;
        private readonly ICharSequence[] titles;

        public EmojiTabsPagerAdapter(AndroidX.Fragment.App.FragmentManager fm, AndroidX.Fragment.App.Fragment[] fragments, ICharSequence[] titles) : base(fm)
        {
            this.fragments = fragments;
            this.titles = titles;
        }
        public override int Count
        {
            get
            {
                return fragments.Length;
            }
        }

        public override AndroidX.Fragment.App.Fragment GetItem(int position)
        {          
            return fragments[position];            
        }
        public override ICharSequence GetPageTitleFormatted(int position)
        {
            //return titles[position];
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Tabs are appearing but Fragments are not loading, The results are the following

[image]

Where it should load RECENT and PEOPLE fragments on each tab, my Fragment XML is the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"    
   android:background="@color/green">
  <TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="RECENTS"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And fragment's code is the following (for RECENT)

```
public class Recent : AndroidX.Fragment.App.Fragment
    {
        public static Recent NewInstance()
        {
            var frag = new Recent { Arguments = new Bundle() };
            return frag;
        }

        public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Create your fragment here
        }

        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.fragment_emoji_recent, container, false);
            return view;
        }
    }
```

Any Idea what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use two Fragments: `TabFragment1`, `TabFragment2` to test. In your code, you did provide the code about `SetupWithViewPager`.

The code below works well for me.

```
 void setupViewPager(Android.Support.V4.View.ViewPager viewPager)
    {
        var adapter = new Adapter(SupportFragmentManager);
        adapter.AddFragment(new TabFragment1(), "First Fragment");
        adapter.AddFragment(new TabFragment2(), "Second Fragment");
                   viewPager.Adapter = adapter;
        viewpager.Adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
        //viewpager.OffscreenPageLimit(4);
    }
```

In MainActivity, you could set like below.

```
  var tabLayout = FindViewById<TabLayout>(Resource.Id.tabs);
        tabLayout.SetupWithViewPager(viewpager);
```

[image]

You could download the source file from the link: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/xamarin-android-create-viewpager-tablayout-floatingactionbutton-supportacti/

Comment: My Activity is FragmentActivity `public class my_activity : FragmentActivity`

Comment: It does not matter. Start the activity and set the view. You could download the project  to check it. If you do not know how to do that, you could provide more code with questions.

Comment: I added where I am initialising the adapter in my activity, please have a look at `In my Activity OnCreate initializing the following` Also when I used `var adapter = new Adapter(SupportFragmentManager);` method it does not even set the Tabs

Comment: Here, we use SupportFragmentManager to create New Adapter Class below the setupViewPager. Tabs was set in the layout and then add the layout to TabFragment. At last add Fragment to adapter with the code `adapter.AddFragment(new TabFragment1(), "First Fragment");`. If you still have question about this, feel free to let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Did this work before moving to AndroidX?

I think you may need to pass ChildFragmentManager instead of FragmentManager to your PagerAdapter.

Comment: I first implemented it in AndroidX, Looking into ChildFragmentManager